# Method get of ActionController::TestCase ignores routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, controller

I'm running into issue which seems to indicate that ActionController::TestCase.get() method ignores what I have in routes.rb.

Rails version is 3.0.10.

I have the following RSpec2 test of my XmlRpcController#index action:

```
it "should get nothing in response to GET request" do
  get :index
  response.response_code.should == 400 #bad_request
end
```

And the only line related to this route in routes.rb is:

```
post 'rpc', :to => "xml_rpc#index"
```

'rake routes' also shows only this route defined.

As a result when I run this test that action actually DOES get executed! I judge this by putting a simple puts inside it) and also a log contains:

> Processing by XmlRpcController#index as HTML

Also if I go to 'localhost:3000/rpc' in browser - it says no route found: just like it should. But tests have other behavior and this puzzles me...

Can anybody hint my why does this happen? I'm only starting learning about RoR :)
Earlier it seemed to me that these 'get/post' methods of TestCase do respect routes.rb...

Am I missing something obvious? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that 'get :index' method is ignoring the routes.rb indeed.

The real solution for me was to use *be_routable* rspec matcher written for this particular purpose:

```
  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      { :get => '/rpc' }.should_not be_routable
    end
  end
```

Figured this out thanks to some user from Ruby-Forum. More info [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rubyonrails-talk/-iIG_j6Fylk/discussion).